# Laravel:Failed to update data

Tags: laravel-5

Dear team please help me 
here is my function

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    DB::table('ssrareqs')
        ->where('req_id',$id)
        ->update(['status_req'=>'reject']);

    return back();
}
```

and below my blade

```
<td>&nbsp; <a style="color: red" href="{{action('ApproverController@destroy', $approvereqs->req_id)}}">Reject</a></td>
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Can you specify your problem, please?

Comment: sorted thanks its didint show any error message